# Is it safe to restore a backup while accepting new queries?

Tags: mariadb, galera

Is it safe to restore a backup while my galera cluster is running and still accepting new queries?

If not what is the recommended way to restore a backup? Before using a cluster I would just use ufw to block all connections to the database port but if I do this I risk making all the nodes disconnect from each other too

Comment: What kind of backup restore are you doing? I'm assuming some partial mariadb-dump restore of a table/db. How was this generated? Does the restore need to go to all galera nodes? Is there going to be applications modifing the data being restored during the restore?

Comment: If your server accepts external queries while restoring from the backup then you may have some problems. The restoring is a process when a bunch of CREATE/INSERT queries is executed. If the client queries the data which is restored partially then it will receive incorrect result, or the query will fail (for example, when slave table is not restored yet). If the client alters data, then this may cause the restoring fall (for example, when the row to be restored become a duplicate due to externally inserted row using autoincrement).

Comment: It's a full database made with mysqldump, and clients do read/write data too. I want to make sure that after a restore the database is exactly like the backup was

Comment: The backup may have `DROP TABLE` and even `DROP DATABASE`.  If so, it is definitely not safe.

Comment: If users are inserting rows, during the reload, there is no way for the database to be exactly like it was before those inserts!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Your Application relies on all the right Data being in all the right Tables for it to work properly, if at all.  While the restore is running, there might be data in *some* tables but not *others* and, at some point in the process, *no tables at all*!

Surprising as it may seem, restoring a database is *destructive*.
You are *destroying* the running database and reloading it with data backed-up at a previous point in time.

To use a movie analogy, restoring a database is *not* like jumping into your DeLorean and whizzing back to 1955 and *still* knowing everything that's happened since.  After the restore, your database will be *as it was* in 1955; everything that's happened since will be *wiped away*.  (Elvis Presley's "Heartbreak Hotel" and Charlton Heston's "The Ten Commandments" (both released in 1956) would simply *not exist*).

This is *not* an activity to be taken lightly, and should *only* be undertaken in your Production system in the most *dire* of circumstances.

I have to ask: *Why do you feel the need to do this?*

Of course, you absolutely need to doing this with a ***copy*** of your Production database, to ensure that your backups really *can* be restored, but that's another story.

> It's a full database made with mysqldump... clients do read/write data too. I want to make sure that after a restore the database is exactly like the backup was

The only way to do that is to lock everybody out of the database, restore it, then open it back up, in the restored state (which will be "exactly like the backup was").  Letting people in to make changes while the restore runs undermines this objective.